# EFCore, many-to-many, DB First, navigation properties not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to map to an existing database. When I use the below code and pull a list of results for a given entity, I get back the results I expect.

However, when I attempt to add `.Include(x => x.Book)` to a simple list query against the `UserBook` table, my result set returns empty.

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName{ get; set; }

    // Reference
    public ICollection<UserBook> UserBooks { get; set; }
}

[Table("Book")]
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public Guid BookId { get; set; }
    public string BookName{ get; set; }

    // Reference
    public ICollection<UserBook> UserBooks { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserBook")]
public class UserBook
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid BookId { get; set; }
    public int PermissionMask { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    // Ref
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

I'm following the instructions layed out here: http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration

To better illustrate the issue, here are the queries I'm using:

```
// Returns 1,000+ rows.
_context.UserBooks.ToList();

// Returns 1 row
_context.UserBooks
    .Where(x => x.UserId == "SomeGuid")
    .ToList();

// Returns 0 rows
_context.UserBooks
    .Include(x => x.Book)
    .Where(x => x.UserId == "SomeGuid")
    .ToList();

// Returns 0 rows
_context.UserBooks.Include(x => x.Book).ToList();
```

Comment: `my UserBook table uses a Primary Key of UserId`, I wonder how this works if it's a many-to-many relationship

Comment: I was going off a diagram I was provided; Double checking SSMS, I see that it is using a composite key. Should have checked the source first, that's my bad. Updated question to reflect this, but initial issue still stands.

Comment: Can you show us the query that is failing?

Comment: Examples added :+1:

Comment: Next step is to investigate the executed SQL of the failing statements.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this. I ran the same queries and got correct results for each of them instead of 0. Can you share a example code which can generate the issue you are seeing

Comment: Your mapping indicates a non-nullable foreign key (so EF will generate an inner join in the query). Try changing datatype on the foreign keys from Guid to Guid? and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I think EF would complain that UserBook entity does not have keys defined, not sure how you got it to work. But to make the include work I believe you need to be explicit on the composite key. Try adding the following to your `DbContext` class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserBook>(e => e.HasKey(c => new { c.UserId, c.BookId }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping indicates a non-nullable foreign key (so EF will generate an inner join in the query). Try changing datatype on the foreign keys from Guid to Guid? and try again.